# How to set the default command prompt properties in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a command prompt shortcut which I customized to have a different font, etc. than the default. It works well, but when I start a batch file with the task scheduler then it uses the default command prompt settings to display batch progress.

How can I customize the default command prompt which the system uses to have the same settings as my customized shortcut?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a command window, right click over the title and select "Defaults".

You get the same dialog as for "Properties" but this sets the default (dur) for all subsequent command prompts.